# Errors when I try to use titlesec

Tags: lyx, titlesec

I'm trying to use titlesec with LyX 2.2.2. When I add this line:

```
 \usepackage{titlesec}
```

to my LaTeX preamble then run LaTeX I get this error:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

followed by complaints about missing }'s

The document class is Report (Standard class) and I have nothing selected in the Modules pane of the LyX settings. The preamble consists of just `\usepackage{titlesec}` and the entire document is just a title and a table. The error occurs only if `\usepackage{titlesec}` is in the preamble.
 Screenshots of the complete document, the preamble in Settings, and the error message follow.
[image: Document window]
[image: LaTeX preamble]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a complete preamble (MWE), please?

Comment: Load `titlesec` *per se* cannot produce any error in a simple article like `\section{xx} foo` so you must show what your are doing wrong. The way to do this is make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: I've updated the question with details of the minimal example to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Clyde please add a minimal example .lyx file. Please read [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) LyX-specific page for an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there's more than what you described. Your caption is in `Paragraph*` formatting. 
Check what's in View>Source. The relevant part should read

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Column} 
\end{table}
```

not

```
\begin{table}
\paragraph*{\protect\caption{Column}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I originally added the table it was in Paragraph formatting, no idea why, that's just what LyX did. I changed it to Paragraph* but that had no effect. The error message didn't exactly point me in the right direction.

Comment: Everything within the float:Table should be in "Plain Layout". I wonder why you ever had it as Paragraph.